# What is the exact math used in SecKeyRawSign in ECC mode that is stored in the enclave?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cryptography, digital-signature, touch-id

I need to compare operation of [SecKeyRawSign](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyRawSign) with other function we are currently using.

What is the exact internal operation of this function when used with ECC256?

I need to verify that point compression is being used, and to verify other compatibility nuances.